# Dismiss a modal view through popover's table row in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

In my app, I presented a modal view. In modal view, I taken a view(Extraview) which contains a table view & a button.

from this button, i open a popview which contains a view(LeftsideView).

```
-(IBAction)popOverBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    LeftSideVCViewController *popUp=[[LeftSideVCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftSideVCViewController" bundle:nil];



    popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];
    popView.delegate =self;

    [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 700)];
    [popView presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(150,30,20,40) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}
```

[image]
[image]

**Now, I want to dismiss modal view on the selection of table row of leftside view.
How can i do this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your Issue Presenting PopOver is a different Class and dismiss Method is a Different Class So you need to Implementing `NSNotificationCenter` like Bellow:-

add Notification at Your PopOVer Created Class in your `ViewDidLoad` Method:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(dismisPopoverInnerPageTeam:)
                                                 name:@"InnerPop"
                                               object:nil];


    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)dismisPopoverInnerPageTeam:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [yourPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now you just need to call this method From your `LeftSideVCViewController` class `UITableView Delegate` method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"InnerPop" object:self];

}
```

Hope it's Helps you:)

Comment: I also tried this,but getting error like: [Reader_View dismissModal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb494e10 2013-01-08 16:12:00.468 AFFeedsReader[3449:1d903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Reader_View dismissModal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb494e10

Comment: remove dismis modelViewCode youjust need to dismiss Popover not ModelView And how To dismisModelView whithout Open it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

Comment: i don't try to dismiss popover, i want to dismiss presented modal view.

Comment: Try with this: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

I solved This as follow:

after register for post Notification.

You must have to dismiss the popover first & then dismiss the presented modal view.

```
-(void)dismissModal:(NSNotification *)notification
{

     [popView dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```